# How to set result queue in celery result backend RPC?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Documentation says, that "RPC-style result backend, using reply-to and one queue per client."

So, how to set result queue in rpc result backend?

I need it for that cases:

1. I'm doing result=send_task('name',args) in one script (and saving result.id as send_task_id) and trying to get result in another script with asyncresult = AsyncResult(id=send_task_id). I can't get this result because each script has own connection to broker and rpc declare own  result queue for each client.
2. In second case I try send_task and AsyncResult (with retry when result.state == PENDING) in one script. When I run it as worker with concurrency = 1 it is OK. When concurrency >1 result may be never returned. Each worker fork get own connection to broker and own result queue. It will be OK when same worker fork doing send_task and proceed retry.

I'm using celery 4.0.2 and 4.1.0.

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the result?

Comment: In first case I tried send task to Rabbit in first script: result=send_task('name',args) and tried to get result in second script: asyncresult = AsyncResult(id=send_task_id). So, I've got no result, because second script watch resгult in different result queue.

Comment: Because first case doesn't work for me, I tried send_task and get result in one script (in my case it was celery worker). By default worker starts with concurrency equals to the number of CPUs available on the machine (in my case it was 4). And I've got no results too, because each thread watch result in different queues.